Static IPv6 connectivity with netctl
I recently switched my virtual private server hehoe.de from Ubuntu to Arch Linux. I am struggling trying to regain IPv6 connectivity. Access via IPv4 is working fine, so the hardware is okay.
The server provider instructs me to use 2a00:5080:1:199::1/128 for the server's IPv6 address and fe80::1 as the gateway. They gave me a configuration file to use with netctl for IPv4 connectivity. I added the IPv6 sections:
Description='A basic static ethernet connection'
Interface=enX0
Connection=ethernet
IP=static
Address=('84.38.64.200/32')
Routes=('172.16.147.1/32 dev eth0')
Gateway='172.16.147.1'
IP6=static
Address6=('2a00:5080:1:199::1')
Gateway6='fe80::1'

After enabling and starting the profile, the command ip addr list shows this:
enX0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:16:3e:4f:7f:20 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 84.38.64.200/32 scope global enX0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2a00:5080:1:199::1/128 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe4f:7f20/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

It makes me think the addresses are set-up correctly.
The command ip -6 route shows this:
2a00:5080:1:199::1 dev enX0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enX0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::1 dev enX0 metric 1024 pref medium

The routes are looking fine to me, too.
I can ping -6 fe80::1%enX0 so there is some machine there.
Running mtr -6 google.com on the server only shows an empty table. That made me think the gateway is not being considered at all.
Observing the ping attempts with tcpdump -e -n -i enX0 "ip6":
18:44:45.981952 00:16:3e:4f:7f:20 > fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv6 (0x86dd), length 118: 2a00:5080:1:199::1 > 2a00:1450:4001:81c::2003: ICMP6, echo request, id 8, seq 3, length 64

Where 2a00:1450:4001:81c::2003 is the google server I tried to ping.
ip neigh shows:
172.16.147.1 dev enX0 lladdr fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff REACHABLE 
fe80::1 dev enX0 lladdr fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff router STALE 

So fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff is indeed the router's MAC address.
Any ideas how to debug this issue?

Trying an mtr against that IP (2a00:5080:1:199::1) gives me 2001:1608:ffff:179:0:20:4119:2 as the last reachable hop, your machine never responds.  fe80::/64 is a link-local address, that won't be routing.

Yes, the machine does not respond. That is the problem. Does the gateway need to be on a route-able address in IPv6?

That's what it's like on my machine, but that is ubuntu and acquires its settings from my router via DHCP. My first hop is my router's public IP.

@tink: Link-local addresses are fairly standard for gateways/nexthops (as the route nexthop address by definition has to be resolvable to a MAC address on the local link, whereas its routability beyond that is completely irrelevant). If it's pingable, then the problem likely is elsewhere.

My suggested next steps would be (as usual) install tcpdump or tshark and check whether any packets are being sent over enX0 (whatever that weird interface name is): tcpdump -e -n -i enX0 "not port 22" or tcpdump -e -n -i enX0 "ip6". When trying to reach e.g. google.com, you should see packets going to your gateway's MAC address.

Good idea, @grawity. I added tcpdump's output to the question body. The packets seem to be sent to the correct address. I am starting to suspect my configuration is not actually wrong, but it is the router that has stopped routing IPv6 packets. I'll probably need to get in touch with the server provider's support again. This provider uses Xen for virtualization. I suspect that is where enX0 is derived from.

fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff is a weird MAC address, but a valid one anyway, and the tcpdump and ip nei output seems okay.
